# DataStage 11.3 Assembly Editor flash popup

Tags: windows, flash, group-policy, datastage, rsl

Our organisation is in the process of upgrading from DataStage 9.1 to 11.3. 
Problem: The DataStage 11.3 Assembly Editor fails to display, and falls over with an error.

Backend OS:
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
Linux   2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 12 16:05:43 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Client OS:
Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (ok, it’s bootcamp Windows running on a Mac). Flash player 16 ActiveX (latest version).

We raised a ticket with IBM and they said it was a flash player problem and we should install the debugger version of flash to get a trace file. After completing the trace, we managed to capture the following error:
RSL Error 1 of 3 (can also be 2 or 3 of 3, in no particular order)
Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https:/// /ibm/iis/ds/xmlpack3/XMLPackLibrary.swf
Note: There are three swf (flash player) files in that server location. The RSL error #2032 error could occur on any one of the following:

1. ISD_UI_Theme.swf
2. XMLPackController.swf
3. XMLPackLibrary.swf

One important factor in this upgrade is that we have installed the backend of DataStage in the Amazon AWS cloud, and have installed the client tools on our local network. So this should not be factor, given that the client tools access the back via HTTP or HTTPS. Our DevOps guys have said that the domain that is giving us problems is probably our local windows domain (and the security within it). We don’t believe that having the backend on an AWS host is the cause of the problem. We have tried to eliminate the AWS cloud (and our local Group Policies) out of the equation, by creating a Windows 2008 server in the AWS cloud on a Bastion Host, with local administrator access. We had a lot of problems with Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration. We had to force it to turn off by hacking the registry. Once we could get past the IE problems, we managed to replicate the exact 2032 error on the 2008 server as my Windows 7 machine on the LAN.

The only way we can get the Assembly Editor to work is to log in as the local Administrator user on the 2008 server. No other user works, even if they have full Administrator rights and nothing else.  We’ve tried everything on this and relaxed all security measures that we can think of. Something appears to be blocking the flash player plugin that is launched from DataStage via a custom Internet Explorer session.

One test that IBM recommended is to access the swf files directly in the browser by substituting the URL :
https:///ibm/iis/ds/xmlpack3/index.html
https:///ibm/iis/ds/XMLPackController.swf

This test works OK, which means that Flash Player is installed and functioning. What is interesting is that the URL prompts for a username and password. That leads me to think that the problem exists in the handshake of credentials between the flash player and the backend and/or what directories the flash player can write to.

Has anybody found a resolution to this problem? Currently our upgrade to 11.3 is at a standstill until we get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found a solution to our own problem. There is a setting in Internet Explorer that if turned on, can block the download of the SWF files to the local machine. This can be found in the Security section of the Advanced tab in the Internet options:

*Do not save encrypted pages to disk*

This setting must be turned off. We had turned it on because it was recommended by SalesForce. If turned on, the SWF files will not be saved and therefore will not execute. The result is an RSL #2032 stream error.

This fixed the problem immediately. Now we just need to apply the setting to our Group Policies for the domain.

I hope this helps other DataStage users. This one had us confused for days!